# NameError: uninitialized constant User from (pry) error in ORM and sqlite3 project?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have the following sql file for a basic data base that logs users, questions, liked and their respective relationships:

```
--- questions.rb
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    fname CHAR(50),
    lname CHAR(50),
    question_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES questions(id)
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    body CHAR(100), 
    asscio_author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (asscio_author_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE question_follows (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_follow_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    question_follow_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_follow_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (question_follow_id) REFERENCES questions(id)
);
-- Add a replies table --

-- Each reply should contain a reference to the subject question.
-- Each reply should have a reference to its parent reply.
-- Each reply should have a reference to the user who wrote it.
-- Don't forget to keep track of the body of a reply.
-- "Top level" replies don't have any parent, but all replies have a subject question.
-- It's okay for a column to be self referential; a foreign key can point to a primary key in the same table.

CREATE TABLE replies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    reply_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subject_question_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    parent_reply_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    author_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    body CHAR(100),

    FOREIGN KEY (subject_question_id) REFERENCES questions(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_reply_id) REFERENCES replies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE question_likes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    question_liked_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    user_liked_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (question_liked_id) REFERENCES questions(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_liked_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
); 

INSERT INTO 
    users (fname, lname)
VALUES
    ('Sanad', 'Washa'),
    ('Michelle','Sinclair'),
    ('Bobbi', 'Starr'),
    ('Rebecca','Linares'),
    ('Nacho','Vidal'),
    ('Monste','Swinger'),
    ('Chasity','Lynn'),
    ('Natural','Nasty'),
    ('Sarah','Young'),
    ('Sandra','Lane'),
    ('Pinky','Booty'),
    ('Priya','Rai'),
    ('Nina','Hartley'),
    ('Gianna','Michaels'),
    ('Imani','Seduction'),
    ('Crissy','Coxxx'),
    ('Carter','Cruise'),
    ('Stoya','Carter');
```

Above is basic data base one may see in an online web application popular today.

Bellow I created a ruby file using an ORM to create, query, build and mechanize the data base to be useful and be represented in objects within an online web application:

```
# questionsdatabase.rb
require 'sqlite3'
require 'pry'
require 'singleton'
require_relative 'question.rb'
require_relative 'question_follow.rb'
require_relative 'question_like.rb'
require_relative 'reply.rb'
require_relative 'comments.rb'

class QuestionsDatabase < SQLite3::Database
    include Singleton
  
    def initialize
      super('questions.db')
      self.type_translation = true
      self.results_as_hash = true
    end
  end
```

```
# user.rb
require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
require_relative 'question.rb'
require_relative 'question_follow.rb'
require_relative 'question_like.rb'
require_relative 'reply.rb'
require_relative 'comments.rb'

class User
    attr_accessor :user_id, :fname, :lname, :question_id
    def.self.all 
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        data.map { |datum| User.new(datum) }
    end

    def self.find_by_id(user_id)
     user = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, user_id)
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            users 
        WHERE 
            user_id = ? 
     SQL
        User.new(user.first)
    end

    def find_by_name(fname, lname)
        puts('naaad')
    end

    def initialize(options)
        @user_id = options['user_id']
        @fname = options['fname']
        @lname = options['lname']
        @question_id = options['question_id']
    end

    def create 
        raise"#{self} already in database" if @user_id 
        QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, @fname, @lname, @question_id, @user_id)
            UPDATE 
                users
            SET 
                fname = ?, lname = ?, question_id = ?
            WHERE   
                user_id = ?
        SQL 
end
```

```
#questions.rb

require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
require_relative 'question.rb'
require_relative 'question_follow.rb'
require_relative 'question_like.rb'
require_relative 'reply.rb'
require_relative 'comments.rb'

class Question 
    attr_accessor :title, :body, :asscio_author_id
    
    def.self.all 
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM questions")
    end
    

    def self.find_by_id (id)
        Question = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id)
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            questions
        WHERE
            id = ?
        SQL
        Question.new(question.id)
    end

    def self.find_by_title
    end

    def initialize (options)
        @id = options['id']
        @title = options['title']
        @body = options['body']
        @asscio_author_id = options['asscio_author_id']
    end
end
```

```
#question_like.rb

require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
require_relative 'question.rb'
require_relative 'question_follow.rb'
require_relative 'question_like.rb'
require_relative 'reply.rb'
require_relative 'comments.rb'

class QuestionLike
    attr_accesor :question_liked_id, :user_liked_id
    def.self.all 
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM question_likes")
    end
    def self.find_by_id (id)
        QuestionLike = QuestionDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id)
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            question_likes
        WHERE 
            id = ?
        SQL
        QuestionLike.new(questionlike.id)
    end
    
    def initialize (options)
        @id = options['id']
        @question_liked_id = options['question_liked_id']
        @user_liked_id = options['user_liked_id']
    end
end
```

```
# question_follow.rb

require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
require_relative 'question.rb'
require_relative 'question_follow.rb'
require_relative 'question_like.rb'
require_relative 'reply.rb'
require_relative 'comments.rb'

class QuestionFollow
    attr_accessor :user_follow_id, :question_follow_id

    def.self.all 
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM question_follows")
    end

    def self.find_by_id (id)
        QuestionFollow = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id)
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            question_follows 
        WHERE 
            id = ?
        SQL 
        QuestionFollow.new(questionfollow.id)
    end
    
    def initialize (options)
        @id = options['id']
        @user_follow_id = options['user_follow_id']
        @question_follow_id = options['question_follow_id']
    end
end
```

```
# reply.rb

require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
class Reply 
    attr_accessor :reply_id, :subject_question_id, :parent_reply_id, :author_user_id, :body
    def self.all
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM replies")
    end

    def self.find_by_id (id)
        Reply = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id)
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            replies
        WHERE
            id = ?
        SQL
        Reply.new(reply.id)
    end
    
    def initialize (options)
        @id = options['id']
        @reply_id = options['reply_id']
        @subject_question_id = options['subject_question_id']
        @parent_reply_id = options['parent_reply_id']
        @author_user_id = options['author_user_id']
        @body = options['body']
    end
end
```

```
# gemfile 
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

 gem "rails"
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'pry'
```

There is questions.db file.

```
SQLite format 3
```

Above is my changes as suggested by debugger.

I receive the following in Pry:

> bash-5.1$ cat import_db.sql | sqlite3 questions.db bash-5.1$ bundle
> install Using rake 13.0.6 Following files may not be writable, so sudo
> is needed:   /usr/bin   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/build_info
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/cache   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/doc
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/plugins
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
> Using i18n 1.10.0 Using minitest 5.15.0 Using tzinfo 2.0.4 Using
> activesupport 7.0.2.3 Using builder 3.2.4 Using erubi 1.10.0 Using
> racc 1.6.0 Using nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-linux) Using
> rails-dom-testing 2.0.3 Using crass 1.0.6 Using loofah 2.15.0 Using
> rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2 Using actionview 7.0.2.3 Using rack 2.2.3
> Using rack-test 1.1.0 Using actionpack 7.0.2.3 Using nio4r 2.5.8 Using
> websocket-extensions 0.1.5 Using websocket-driver 0.7.5 Using
> actioncable 7.0.2.3 Using globalid 1.0.0 Using activejob 7.0.2.3 Using
> activemodel 7.0.2.3 Using activerecord 7.0.2.3 Using marcel 1.0.2
> Using mini_mime 1.1.2 Using activestorage 7.0.2.3 Using mail 2.7.1
> Using digest 3.1.0 Using io-wait 0.2.1 Using timeout 0.2.0 Using
> net-protocol 0.1.2 Using strscan 3.0.1 Using net-imap 0.2.3 Using
> net-pop 0.1.1 Using net-smtp 0.3.1 Using actionmailbox 7.0.2.3 Using
> actionmailer 7.0.2.3 Using actiontext 7.0.2.3 Using bundler 2.3.9
> Using coderay 1.1.3 Using method_source 1.0.0 Using pry 0.14.1 Using
> thor 1.2.1 Using zeitwerk 2.5.4 Using railties 7.0.2.3 Using rails
> 7.0.2.3 Using sqlite3 1.4.2 Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 50 gems now installed. Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a
> bundled gem is installed. bash-5.1$ cat import_db.sql | sqlite3
> questions.db bash-5.1$ pry [1] pry(main)> User.new('fname' => 'ned'
> ,'lname'=>'tevin', 'question_id'=>1, 'user_id'=>0) NameError:
> uninitialized constant User from (pry):1:in `__pry__' [2] pry(main)> s = User.new('user_id'=>1,'fname' => 'ned' ,'lname'=>'tevin', 'user_id'=>0) (pry):2: warning: key "user_id" is duplicated and overwritten on line 2 NameError: uninitialized constant User from (pry):2:in` **pry**' [3] pry(main)>

Comment: I did that and got this in pry: 
```

[1] pry(main)> User.new
NameError: uninitialized constant User
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
[2] pry(main)> User.new(1,'a','b',2)
NameError: uninitialized constant User
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'
[3] pry(main)> 

```

Comment: Why should they be in their own file? Is that a Ruby convention or a rule in the Ruby language? I don't like playing around to see if Ruby will accept something because I just need to know if what I am writing is proper or not.

Comment: I made the requested changes and I am still getting the same error. Why are constants uninitialized and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'
require 'pry'
require_relative './question.rb'
require_relative './question_follow.rb'
require_relative './question_like.rb'
require_relative './reply.rb'
require_relative './comments.rb'
require_relative './questionsdatabase.rb'
class User
    attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :question_id
    def self.all 
        data = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        data.map { |datum| User.new(datum) }
    end

    def self.find_by_id(user_id)
     user = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, user_id)
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            users 
        WHERE 
            user_id = ? 
     SQL
        User.new(user.first)
    end

    def find_by_name(fname, lname)
        puts('naaad')
    end

    def initialize(options)
        @user_id = options['user_id']
        @fname = options['fname']
        @lname = options['lname']
        @question_id = options['question_id']
    end

    #def create 
    #    raise"#{self} already in database" if @user_id 
    #    QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, @fname, @lname, @question_id)
    #        INSERT INTO 
    #            users(fname, lname, question_id)
    #        VALUES
    #            (?,?,?)
    #    SQL 
    #end
end

[2] pry(main)> exit
bash-5.1$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require './user.rb'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> s = User.new('fname' => 'ned' ,'lname'=>'tevin', 'question_id'=>0)
=> #<User:0x00000000025663f8 @fname="ned", @lname="tevin", @question_id=0, @user_id=nil>
[3] pry(main)>
```

I fixed the required code, mainly with user and loaded the user file in pry and was able to create the object.